# Char* as YYSTYPE in flex/bison returning only first character in token when used with strdup() in lexer

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis, parser-generator

I am using a `char*` as `YYSTYPE` in a compiler built with flex and bison.  The line

```
#define YYSTYPE char*
```

is at the top of my grammar file.  A few of the tokens in my lexer need to pass the entire string that they match to my grammar, and the others just need to pass their token, so this works well for me.  I do this sort of thing in my lexer:

```
[(foo|bar)]    {yylval = *strdup(yytext); return FOOBAR;}
```

In my grammar, I use them with productions like this one:

```
fb:
    FOOBAR
    {
        sprintf($$, "%s", &$1);
    }
    ;
```

This sets the value of `$$` to the first character in the original matched token.  I (probably) understand why, since a dereferenced `char*` is a `char`, but the steps I took to fix it caused problems.  For instance, removing the `&` from the `sprintf()` line causes a segfault.  Removing the `*` from the assignment causes a "makes integer from pointer without a cast".  What do I do?  I think the problem lies in the assignment to `yylval`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems with what you are doing. First and foremost, since `YYSTYPE` is a char pointer, there is actually no space allocated for a string. So when you do `sprintf($$, "%s", &$1)`, you try to print a string into a pointer that is not initialized (`$$` is a pointer, but not initialized to anything, so it can point to anywhere in memory.)

Another problem *might* be your use of `&$1` in the `sprintf`. It takes the address of the pointer, not the actual string the pointer is pointing to.

A third problem is you are using `strdup` in the lexer, which allocates memory. But you never free it somewhere, creating a memory leak.

The fourth and final problem is why you only get a single character, and you are actually lucky you get that, and that because while `strdup(yytext)` is returning a copy of a string, the star in front of it returns the dereferenced pointer which is a char. So you set the pointer to a single character.

**Edit:** I hope it all makes sense, it's late and I might have a glass of wine or two...

Comment: Yes.  I'm actually using `asprintf()`, which allocates more memory and causes another memory leak.  In addition, I'm doing the memory freeing elsewhere.  Sorry not to have included that, didn't want to dump a wall of text.  The issue was the last thing... but I still get that warning.  How do I fix the "makes integer from a pointer without cast" problem?

Answer (score 4):

Change the assignment back to `yylval = strdup(yytext)`, change `sprintf(...)` to `$$ = yylval`. Make sure the `YYSTYPE` is defined in your parser (`.y`) file, and that that header is created and imported into your lexer (`.l`) file.

---

I had hoped to use just `YYSTYPE`, but I couldn't get that to work, so use `%union{}`.
After experimenting and going back a bit, I got it to work with these changes:

In your `parser.y`:

```
%{
%}

%output "parser.c"
%defines "parser.h"

%union {
    char *str;
}

%type <str> fb
%start fb

%token FOOBAR

%%
fb: FOOBAR { $$ = yylval.str; }
%%
```

In your `lexer.l`:

```
%{
#include <string.h> 
#include "parser.h"
%}

%option outfile="lexer.c"
%option header-file="lexer.h"

%%
[(foo|bar)] { yylval.str = strdup(yytext); return FOOBAR; }
%%
```

Note:

1. You will need to define `yyerror`, `yywrap`, and `main` somewhere.
2. As it stands, this doesn't `free` the string, you'll need to figure out where best to do that.

Comment: It actually can work with char*, I just did it.  But thanks, this would also work.

Comment: Nice example but it is a bit bloated to use a union for just a string.

Answer (score 3):

I solved that with following (both in .l and .y before .tab.h #include):

```
#ifndef YYSTYPE
# define YYSTYPE char*
#endif
```

Comment: Seems does not work for Regex.
Error: `error: request for member ‘string’ in something not a structure or union`
Such as:

`[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*         { yylval.string = strdup(yytext); return(ID); }`

`[1-9][0-9]*|\.[0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]\.|[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]* { yylval.string = strdup(yytext); return(NUMBER); }`

`\'(\\.|[^\\'\n])*\'          { yylval.string = strdup(yytext); return(STRING); }`